# R as.Date function

Tags: r, as.date

as often I have problems with the conversion of dates in R. Can anybody explain the following behavior to me?

```
as.Date('Dec-28-2003', '%b-%d-%Y') # returns NA
as.Date('Jan-04-2004', '%b-%d-%Y') # returns 2004-01-04
```

Comment: `as.Date('Dec-28-2003', '%b-%d-%Y')` works for me

Comment: Yeah, I realized it's about the language setting. My R recognizes German dates only... (see answer below). Thanks for checking though!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I got the answer. It's about the language setting, my R recognizes German dates only, i.e.

```
as.Date('Dez-28-2003', '%b-%d-%Y')
```

as in Dezember instead of December works fine. I used the lubricate package instead.

```
mdy('Dec-28-2003') # returns 2003-12-28
```